# Ruby: how to push to a hash inside an array on a CSV

Tags: arrays, ruby, csv, hash

I m new to ruby.
I have two csv files, I m using 'csv' library. I can get the arrays from the CSVs but i dont know how to push to a hash inside the first csv.

I get these two arrays from the CSVs:

```
csv1 = [1,2,{3 => :a},4]
csv2 = [5,6,{7 => :b},8]
```

And i want the first csv file to look like this:

```
[1,2,{3 => :a, 7 => :b},4]
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]". SO isn't for writing code for you, it's to help debug the problem with code you wrote. We expect you to research, to try, and then to ask if you can't figure it out. Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421. We need to see minimal  sample input data that demonstrates the problem. `[1,2,{3 => a, 7 => b},4]` is NOT valid CSV as there are embedded commas, and CSV format won't have closing brackets, so please explain what that is.

Comment: I appreciate the greenie, but I suggest you retract it, at least for the time being. A quick selection may discourage other, possibly better answers, and holding off for awhile is a courtesy to those still preparing answers. My advice is to wait for at least a couple of hours before selecting an answer. There's no rush, just don't forget if you get at least one helpful answer.

Comment: You want to do something with two arrays. Where the arrays came from is not relevant.

Comment: Ok. I will take both comments into consideration. Next time I will wait longer to green a respone, and instead of triyng to "abstrac" the problem i will show the code itself. Thnx again!.

Comment: Code, like a picture, is worth 10_000 words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way.

```
arr1 = [1,2,{ 3 => 'a' },4]
arr2 = [5,6,{ 7 => 'b' },8]

arr1.map do |e|
  case e
  when Hash then e.merge(arr2.select { |e| e.is_a? Hash }.first)
  else e
  end
end
  #=> [1, 2, {3=>"a", 7=>"b"}, 4]
```

When

```
e #=> { 3 => 'a' }

h2 = arr2.select { |e| e.is_a? Hash }.first
  #=> [{ 7 => 'b' }].first
  #    { 7 => 'b' }
e.merge(arr2.select { |e| e.is_a? Hash }.first)
e.merge(h2)
  #=> { 3 => 'a' }.merge({ 7 => 'b' })
  #=> {3=>"a", 7=>"b"}
```

Comment: As always, a cool answer... but wouldn't `arr1.each_with_index.map do |e, index|` be better?  It provides the index for `arr2` and would handle multiple hash array values (instead of just the first)

Comment: @Steve, I didn't know if the two hashes are necessarily at the same offset.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more way to do this:

```
csv1.zip(csv2).collect{|v1, v2| v1.merge(v2) rescue v1 }
```

---

We first combine the two arrays using `zip`

```
csv1 = [1,2,{3 => :a},4]
csv2 = [5,6,{7 => :b},8]

t = csv1.zip(csv2)
#=> [[1, 5], [2, 6], [{3=>:a}, {7=>:b}], [4, 8]]
```

Next, we collect the result of merging two elements of the sub-arrays.  However, since `merge` is only supported on `Hash`, we expect an exception if it is invoked on `Fixnum` like `1` or `2` - in such cases, we will rescue from the exception by returning value of first element of array.

```
t = t.collect{|v1, v2| v1.merge(v2) rescue v1 }
#=> [1, 2, {3=>:a, 7=>:b}, 4]
```

---

*`Array#map` is an alias of `Array#collect` - one can use either based on one's preference in the context of code and its readability*

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Thanks